# Using fieldOptions with Custom Fields

Tags: custom-fields, ajax

I have a "Select list" within a Contribution Form. I want to populate the "Select List" with Custom Field values.

I have created the Custom Group under Contacts, so i want to search all contacts and get the custom field "Title" from that Custom group.

Then depending on the "Option" selected i want field values to populate.

I have tried to use the:

hook_civicrm_fieldOptions but its not working (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_fieldOptions/).

Any advise on how to do this?

Thanks

This is the HTML for field i want to populate:

```
<tr class="custom_field-row custom_276_-1-row">
    <td class="label"><label for="custom_276_-1">Proc Fee</label>
      <a class="helpicon" title="Proc Fee Help" aria-label="Proc Fee Help" href="#" onclick="CRM.help(&quot;Proc Fee&quot;, {&quot;id&quot;:276,&quot;file&quot;:&quot;CRM\/Custom\/Form\/CustomField&quot;}); return false;">&nbsp;</a>    </td>
    <td class="html-adjust">
      <div class="select2-container crm-select2 crm-form-select" id="s2id_custom_276_-1" style="width: 195px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-6">- none -</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen6" class="select2-offscreen">Proc Fee</label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-6" id="s2id_autogen6"><div class="select2-drop select2-display-none crm-container select2-with-searchbox">   <div class="select2-search">       <label for="s2id_autogen6_search" class="select2-offscreen">Proc Fee</label>       <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-6" id="s2id_autogen6_search" placeholder="">   </div>   <ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-6">   </ul></div></div><select class="crm-select2 crm-form-select" data-crm-custom="Commission:Proc_Fee" data-api-entity="Contribution" data-api-field="custom_276" data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/proc_fee_20191113181638" name="custom_276_-1" id="custom_276_-1" tabindex="-1" title="Proc Fee" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">- none -</option>
    <option value="accordpt30">Accord - PT - 0.30%</option>
    <option value="accordresidirect045">Accord - Resi - Direct - 0.45%</option>
</select> <a href="/civicrm/admin/options/proc_fee_20191113181638?reset=1" class="crm-option-edit-link medium-popup crm-hover-button" target="_blank" title="Edit Options" data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/proc_fee_20191113181638"><i class="crm-i fa-wrench"></i></a>&nbsp;
          </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I haven't seen your code, I can only suggest what worked for me:

```
function myext_civicrm_fieldOptions($entity, $field, &$options, $params) {

  if ($entity == 'Contribution') {
    if (isset($field) && $field == 'mycustomfield_123') {
      $myArray = [
        1 => 'Title 1',
        2 => 'Title 2'
      ];
      $options = $myArray;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks this has worked if i associate it with a field on the contrubution form but when i try to link to a custom field for e.g. custom_276_-1. Nothing happens

Comment: @Moe try to set $field == 'custom_276'

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! I need more things to get to my end goal but this really helped.